# ubuntu mate 16.04 & workspace switcher

Tags: 16.04, workspaces, mate

I have some problems on ubuntu mate 16.04 with the workspace switcher. It's a very useful thing to have, and I have set workspace switcher currently to have 6 workspaces, but whenever one of the windows in one of the worspaces gets a notification or finishes an operation or something, the program will jump to the workspace I'm currently on instead of staying where it is, thus negating the root cause of having that many workspaces in the first place.

Example:

Thunderbird is in workspace 1, firefox workspace 2. Let's say I've clicked on a link in a mail in thunderbird, and it opens up in firefox. That's fine, but firefox jumps to the workspace I'm on. How do I prevent that? I can't find the option in the settings for some reason. Please help.

Thanks in advance. :)